# Show all varchar values with PIVOT

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot

I need to show all varchar values with pivot but I'm not sure if that is possible?

I have `OCCUPATIONS` table:

```sql
-----------+------------+
|   NAME    | OCCUPATION |
+-----------+------------+
| Eve       | Actor      |
| Jennifer  | Actor      |
| Ketty     | Actor      |
| Samantha  | Actor      |
| Aamina    | Doctor     |
| Julia     | Doctor     |
| Priya     | Doctor     |
| Ashley    | Professor  |
| Belvet    | Professor  |
| Britney   | Professor  |
| Maria     | Professor  |
| Meera     | Professor  |
| Naomi     | Professor  |
| Priyanka  | Professor  |
| Christeen | Singer     |
| Jane      | Singer     |
| Jenny     | Singer     |
| Kristeen  | Singer     |
+-----------+------------+
```

Pivot query:

```sql
    select NAME, OCCUPATION from OCCUPATIONS 
    ) t
    PIVOT( MAX(NAME) FOR OCCUPATION IN ([Doctor], [Professor], [Singer], [Actor])
    ) as PIVOT_TABLE;
```

Query result:

```sql
+--------+-----------+----------+----------+
| Doctor | Professor |  Singer  |  Actor   |
+--------+-----------+----------+----------+
| Priya  | Priyanka  | Kristeen | Samantha |
+--------+-----------+----------+----------+
```

Above query gives only 1 record in each column but I want to get all.

Comment: Don't post images of data, we can't consume it. Take the time to post it in a consumable format, preferably DDL and DML statements, however, if not then as tabular formatted `text`. Please don't expect the users here to transcribe your data for you. Also, what are your expected results here?

Comment: Also, that query appears to be incomplete. There is a right parenthesis (`)`) prior to the `t` on line 2, however, no starting left parenthesis (`(`).

Comment: "I want to get all" - what does this mean? do you mean you want to still get 4 cells, but with all names, separated by commas, or something else? please include desired _output_ also

Comment: Side Note: SQL Server 2008 has been completely unsupported for over a year, and you should strongly consider getting your upgrade path completed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You 'll need an extra column, e.g. with  `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT RN, [Doctor], [Professor], [Singer], [Actor]
FROM  
(SELECT NAME, OCCUPATION ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY OCCUPATION ORDER BY NAME ) as RN
FROM OCCUPATIONS 
) t
PIVOT( MAX(NAME) FOR OCCUPATION IN ([Doctor], [Professor], [Singer], [Actor])
) as PIVOT_TABLE;
```